# Why is the following matrix not diagonalisable over a complex field?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the following matrix not diagonalisable over a complex field?
\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}

Comment: LaTeX tip: write `\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}` to get
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it does not have two linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue 1.

If you are not familiar with this characterization of diagonalizable matrices, you should really remedy that. An n by n matrix is diagonalizable iff it has n linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Does this hold in both directions? I mean, is that necessary or just sufficient?

Comment: A *characterization* is necessary and sufficient. That's also why I used iff. Check out the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix). It's quite easy to prove.

Comment: Thanks. I was simply curious as I have not reviewed linear algebra in a long time.

Comment: @ChantryCargill no problemo!

Comment: I thought it's eige value is the root of (x-1)^2 +1. So it's eigenvalue is not 1?

Comment: @user136266 : Take another try at the characteristic polynomial: it's just $(x-1)^2$.